# How to estimate the size of byte array/buffer to read from NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, .net, buffer, networkstream

```
int bufferSize = 8192;
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[bufferSize];
```

I need to read from a NetworkStream which would have a continuous flow of incoming data at a high rate. I wanted to know

- What should be the basis for setting the `bufferSize` value?
- Is there a standard "safe" value that
  can be chosen irrespective of the
  enviornment?
- Should it also vary with the Stream
  I'm trying to read from
  (FileStream/NetworkStream/..)?

Please consider performance as the focus point for the estimation.

Comment: Its hard to believe that no one has an answer to this query! Not even pointers towards the best approaches.. :-\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one sure way to optimize performance: measure, measure, measure.

I've seen 1024, 4096 or 8192 used as buffer sizes for downloading files from the internet, and I haven't noticed any significant difference using either one.

Comment: Note that 8192 is really the highest you should go, as the Winsock internal buffer is 8k. Not sure if that has changed in more recent versions of Windows.

Comment: So, should I always max out the read buffer to get the best performance?